# Painting, expected value - probability

Tags: probability, expected-value

You are painting a circle consisting of dots. Each dot is black with probability $1/2$ and white with probability $1/2$, independent of the other dots. After $n$ dots you stop painting and the dots form a circle. You are interested in the expected number of colour changes, whereby the random variable. $X$ describes the numbers of colour changes, i.e. the $i^{th}$ dot is black and the $(i+1)^{th}$ dot is white or vice versa, whereby there is also a possible colour change from the $n^{th}$ dot to the first dot, since they form a circle. How can one calculate this expected value? The cyclic property is giving me some problems, I thought about splitting up $X$ into $X_i$ = dot $i$ and $i+1$ have different colours, but I'm struggling with the case of the last dot and the first dot, since there is some kind of interdependence. I noticed so far that there can only be an even number of colour changes.

Comment: Expected value is linear.  Answer the question for the $1$st dot being different than the $2$nd dot, multiply by $n$, and be done.  Any "*interdependence*" is completely irrelevant and can be ignored.

Comment: @JMoravitz but the transition of the last to the first dot (since it's a circle), doesn't this depend on the colour of the first one, so could you explain why we can treat this case as the others?

Comment: Oh, yes, it certainly *depends* in terms of events being dependent... but that doesn't matter in the slightest thanks to expected value being linear.  The expected value of a sum is always equal to the sum of expected values, even when they were dependent

Answer (score 1):

For $n=2$, there can be $0$ changes or $2$ changes, both with probability $1/2$, so the expected value is $1$.

For $n=3$, there can be $0$ or $2$ changes. If $K$ = the number of changes, $P(K=0) = 2/2^n = 2^{1-n} = 1/4$.  Therefore $P(K=2) = 3/4$, and the expected value is $1.5$.

For $n=4$, there can be $0$ or $2$ or $4$ changes.  $P(K=0) = 2^{1-n} = 1/8$. $ P(K=4) = 1/8$ as well, so $P(K=2$) must be $3/4$. $E[K] = 0 + 2\cdot 3/4 + 4 \cdot 1/8 = 2$

The trend is $1, 1.5, 2,...$ and it makes sense that it would be linear as you keep on adding dots means adding on a proportional number of chances to flip color.  It looks like $E[K] = n/2$

Another way to see it: every dot added gives on average one more chance to flip color, and you would expect it to do so half the time.

Comment: Is the probability for the possible colour change from the last dot to the first dot (circle) any different?

Comment: No, it should be the same everywhere.  If you go to the next dot, no matter where you are, you have a $50%$ chance of a color flip.

Comment: So could I simply say $X_i = 1/2 \cdot 1/2 + 1/2 \cdot 1/2 = 1/2$ and then use the linearity of the expectation value to obtain $E[X] = E[X_1 + X_2 + \ldots] = E[X_1] + \ldots + E[X_n]= n \cdot 1/2$?